# Container for a single h264 video stream

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, x264, libavformat, mkv

I have the code of a simple h264 encoder, which outputs a raw 264 file. I want to extend it to directly output the video in a playable container; it doesn't matter which one as long as it is playable by VLC. So, what is the easiest way to include a wrapper around this raw H264 file?

Everywhere I looked on the web, people used ffmpeg and libavformat, but I would prefer to have standalone code. I do not want fancy stuff like audio, subtiltes, chapters etc., just the video stream.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can output a .264 directly by writing the Elementary stream to a file in AnnexB format. That is, write each NALU to the file separated by start codes (0x00000001). But make sure the stream writes SPS and PPS before the first IDR>

Comment: Yes, the encoder does that already. However, the result is not playable by VLC for example. However, when I use the program mkvmerge to create an mkv file, the video plays fine. I need to add some code to the encoder to create the mkv, or any other wrapper by itself.

Answer (score 0):

mkv, mpeg-ts, mp4 (you can use libMP4v2)